# Why this expression doesn't work?

Tags: manipulate, conditional, broken-code

I am trying to choose a function and then the parameters using `Manipulate`, but isn't working...

```
Manipulate[
     LogLinearPlot[model[h], {h, 0.001, 20000}, PlotRange -> All, 
      Frame -> True],

     Dynamic@Switch[model,
       m1, Column[{Control@{{r, 0.1}, 0, 1}, Control@{{s, 0.5}, 0, 1}, 
         Control@{{a, 20}, 0, 30}, Control@{{n, 1.2}, 1, 2}}],
       m2, Column[{Control@{r, 0, 1}, Control@{s, 0, 1}, 
         Control@{h0, 0.1, 30}, Control@{l, -2, 2}}]],

     Control@{{model, m1, "Model"}, {m1 -> "Model 1", m2 -> "Model 2"}, 
       PopupMenu},

     Initialization :> {
       m1[h_] := r + (s - r)/(1 + (a h)^n)^(1 - 1/n),
       m2[h_] := Piecewise[{{r + (s - r) (h0/h)^l, h > h0}, {s, h < h0}}]
       }]
```

It seems that the parameters only change when I switch from one model to the other and I go back to the previous one.

Comment: Please do not "move the goalposts" in a question, especially after it has been answered.  Instead post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expedient solution is to add the option `TrackedSymbols :> All` to `Manipulate`, or if you wish to be a bit more selective: `TrackedSymbols :> {r, s, a, n, h0, l}`.

As an aside `Manipulate` is an automated but basic GUI tool.  More complicated interfaces may be better crafted on your own from [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html), [`Slider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html), etc.